# WiFi is not detecting in Ubuntu 14.10 - Mac

Tags: wireless, macbook-air

I tried everything to setting up my wifi, because is not detecting anything. After read and done a lot of things I found this page http://pavelmanushin.blogspot.ru/2014/04/ubuntu-12.html which i think has the solution for my problem. The problem is that I don't understand point 7 when it said "And now you need to insert this newly created file into your Ubuntu". What does it means with "my ubuntu"? which folder is it? I inserte the wl.ko file in my personal folder, but then I ran "sudo insmod wl.ko" (point 9) and the terminal shows "insmod: ERROR: could not load module wl.ko: No such file or directory". I think that the problem is that I am not putting the wl.ko file in the correct folder. Nevertheless of this procedure, if someone knows another procedure and want to help, please be my guest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not have to do all of that for 14.10, Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are having a wifi device problem, I had the same kind of problem and it sucked.. I tried everything and yes I also thought that wl.ko is the answer xD but when I tried a USB WiFi device (TP-Link) it automatically connected :) you should try the same maybe it will work out (just an advice) anyways the 7th point means that it will produce a wl.ko file in the top level directory.If your driver does not build, check to make sure you have installed the kernel package described in the requirements above.This driver uses cfg80211 API. Code for Wext API is present and can be built but we have dropped support for it. As before, the Makefile will still build the matching version for your system.

Answer (score 0):

it doesnot really matter where the file is.
Once you change the terminal current folder to the one where the file wl.ko is located then you may give Ubuntu the next commands as stated in the guide.

Answer (score 0):

The blog you have referenced is more or less just a direct copy and paste of the R[EADME file posted on the Broadcom driver page](http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.248.txt).

That being said, this shouldn't be particularly difficult as long as you just follow the steps correctly, one at a time.  I'll try to distill the steps in the blog down some to see if that helps reduce the confusion.

**Download and Compile the Broadcom Driver**

1. Download the correct driver (32 or 64 bit) from the Broadcom download page:
   http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php
2. Extract the file you downloaded to a folder in your home directory (for example ~/hybrid_wl)
3. Navigate to the folder in a terminal (cd ~/hybrid_wl)
4. Run `sudo make clean`
5. Run `sudo make`
6. Run `sudo make install` (I've found that this last step will copy the module to the appropriate directory for you)

**Unload any previously installed modules for Wireless**

1. Run `sudo lsmod | grep "brcmsmac\|b43\|ssb\|bcma\|wl"`
2. Remove any of the following modules that exist from the `lsmod` call

   - `sudo rmmod b43`
   - `sudo rmmod brcmsmac`
   - `sudo rmmod ssb`
   - `sudo rmmod bcma`
   - `sudo rmmod wl`
3. Blacklist the unnecessary drivers to prevent conflicts in the future

   - `sudo echo "blacklist ssb" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`
   - `sudo echo "blacklist bcma" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`
   - `sudo echo "blacklist b43" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`
   - `sudo echo "blacklist brcmsmac" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf"`

**Install the wl.ko driver**

1. You should still be in the same folder that you compiled the source from (e.g. `~/hybrid_wl`.  If not, please `cd ~/hybrid_wl`
2. Load one of the following security modules (typically the first one should work)

   - `sudo modprobe lib80211`
   - `sudo modprobe ieee80211_crypt_tkip`
3. `sudo modprobe cfg80211`
4. `sudo insmod wl.ko`
5. `sudo depmod -a`

At this point your WiFi should be enabled and able to detect wireless networks.  The final step is to update your `initrd` file with your new module configuration.  In Ubuntu, it seems that simply blacklisting `ssb` is not enough.  We must rebuild the initrd file in order for your new module configuration to take effect on boot.

1. Make a backup of your existing initrd: `cp /boot/initrd.img-\`uname -r` ~`
2. `sudo update-initramfs -u`
3. `sudo init 6` (reboot)

At this point your wireless module should successfully load on boot, and you should not have to install again unless a kernel upgrade forces you to recompile the driver.

Comment: Hi Mike, after I tried what you said and read this http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.248.txt y found 1 problems. When I build the drivers with "make clean" and "make" instead of creates a "wl.ko" file creates a "built-in.o". I read here http://listas.canaima.softwarelibre.gob.ve/pipermail/soporte/2009-May/004118.html that if you ran this command "make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`" it will creates the "built-in.o" & "wl.ko" files. Nevertheless, I only have "bild-in.o" file. Can you help me with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Mike, after I tried what you said and read this http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/README_6.30.223.248.txt y found 1 problems. When I build the drivers with "make clean" and "make" instead of creates a "wl.ko" file creates a "built-in.o". I read here http://listas.canaima.softwarelibre.gob.ve/pipermail/soporte/2009-May/004118.html that if you ran this command "make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd`" it will creates the "built-in.o" & "wl.ko" files. Nevertheless, I only have "bild-in.o" file. Can you help me with this? thanks in advance.